# Echo JS variable in Joomla JText

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

Ajax.php, Script tag in php file

```
<script>
 success: function(data) {
    var message = data.message; //Json data 
    if ( data.status == 1 ) {
      jQuery("#msgError").html(<?php echo JText::_(' + message + ');?>);
    } 
 }
```

Is it possible to Echo JS variable in php like above?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a best example,

```
<?php
// In php write following code
JText::script('COM_HELLOWORLD_MESSAGE');

<script>
// Using in Javascript like this
Joomla.JText._('COM_HELLOWORLD_MESSAGE')

// For your example look like
 success: function(data) {
    if ( data.status == 1 ) {
      jQuery("#msgError").html(Joomla.JText._('COM_HELLOWORLD_MESSAGE'));
    } 
 }
;
</script>
```

I already sent code to merge in joomla to make it more advanced. Please check it here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6006 
Also there are many ways to do it which you will find in above link.